# Resolving C++ Name Collision

Tags: c++, namespaces

InitializeQTML is a function in QTML.h.  I'm writing a wrapper and I would like to use the name InitializeQTML for the wrapper function:

```
#include <QTML.h>

public class QuickTime
{ 
  public:  
    static void InitializeQTML(InitializationFlags flag) {
        InitializeQTML((long)flag));
    };
};
```

How can I reference the original InitializeQTML function from inside the wrapper function and avoid the name collision without renaming the wrapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can qualify the name.  If the `QTML` library's `InitializeQTML` function is in the global namespace, you can use this in your `QuickTime::InitializeQTML` static member function to refer to it:

```
::InitializeQTML((long)flag);
^ look in the global namespace
```

Comment: @jnm2: There's a "tick" option to accept an answer here on SO, you should see it to the left.

Comment: I'm waiting until I can.  Right now it says "You can accept an answer in 7 minutes."